# Pythonic way to use an 'slicer' and a 'where'-equivalent on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've got an hierarchical-index pandas dataframe. Therefore I customarily use pd.IndexSlice for slicing the index.  I'm trying to return a fragment of a dataframe which has been IndexSliced and also selected based on values in the column.

I can do this with two lines of code, but it seems gross:

```
foo = (gbed.loc[idx['Squat':'Squat Tempo', :], :])
print foo[foo['Weight'] > 120]
```

I wanted to write this as a single line, though,  but it throws an error

> "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,)
>   (12,)"

```
print (gbed.loc[idx['Squat':'Squat Tempo', :] & gbed['Weight']>100, :])
```

Is there a way to specify this query in a single line?

Full example code below:

```
#make an index with a handful of duplicate dates
dates1 = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=8, freq='D')
dates2 = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=4, freq='D')
dates = dates1.append(dates2)

ex = ['Squat','Squat','Squat Chains','Squat Chains','Squat Pause','SquatPause','Squat Pause','Squat Tempo','Bench','Bench','Bench','Bench',]
wt = [100,120,140,150,150,140,160,172,90,90,100,110]
cols = {'Exercise': ex, 'Weight': wt, 'Date': dates}

sf = pd.DataFrame(cols)

gbed = sf.groupby(['Exercise','Date']).max().sortlevel()
print gbed

idx = pd.IndexSlice

print ("\nall types of squats over 120kg")
#ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (12,) 
#print (gbed.loc[idx['Squat':'Squat Tempo', :] & gbed['Weight']>100, :])

foo = (gbed.loc[idx['Squat':'Squat Tempo', :], :])
print foo[foo['Weight'] > 120]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [110]: gbed.query("Weight > 100 and 'Squat' <= Exercise <= 'Squat Tempo'")
Out[110]:
                         Weight
Exercise     Date
Squat        2011-01-02     120
Squat Chains 2011-01-03     140
             2011-01-04     150
Squat Pause  2011-01-05     150
             2011-01-07     160
Squat Tempo  2011-01-08     172
```

or:

```
In [108]: gbed.loc[idx['Squat':'Squat Tempo', :], :].query("Weight > 100")
Out[108]:
                         Weight
Exercise     Date
Squat        2011-01-02     120
Squat Chains 2011-01-03     140
             2011-01-04     150
Squat Pause  2011-01-05     150
             2011-01-07     160
Squat Tempo  2011-01-08     172
```